# Referencing a string value in excel VBA with the indexed cells property

Tags: excel, vba, loops, cells

VBA Newbie here with a basic question I've been struggling to find the answer on:

I'm trying to run a loop in VBA that looks up a string (or word) and if that word is found, a specified letter has to appear in a cell in the column beside it. This works fine when I use a specific cell reference (eg Cells(72, 10)), but as soon as I try to loop it using an index (eg Cells(i, 10), it gives an error 13 - type mismatch.

The 'strings' I'm looking up are outputs (either "Peak" or "Trough") from another macro I wrote as a basic calculation function in excel. Is the error as a result of trying to reference a different data type than the "Cells" function can recognise? Or is there just a better way to run my loop? Following are the macro and my loop.

```
Function FTrough(tmin2, tmin1, t, tplus1, tplus2)

If t < tmin2 And t < tmin1 And t < tplus1 And t < tplus2 Then
   FTrough = "Trough"
Else
   FTrough = ""
End If


End Function
```

And the loop":

```
Sub Lookup()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim c As Integer

c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To c
    For j = 2 To 141

       If Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 10) = "Trough" Then
          Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 12) = "T"
       End If


       If Worksheets("Austria").Cells(j, 11) = "Peak" Then
          Worksheets("Austria").Cells(j, 12) = "P"
       End If
   Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: The code that writes the P to Austria is inefficient as it writes it to the same worksheet once for every worksheet.

Comment: Yes, I realised my mistake after posting. "Austria" should be replaced by "i". This, however doesn't eliminate the error I keep getting. The error 13 type mismatch persists as soon as I use any sort of index instead of numerical values to reference the cells in the cells property.

Comment: @user5254884 Is this really all the code you have? As EDC stated your code works. Thus I wonder do you have more code that might create the error?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment because my reput is lower than 50, so here is my answer.

Basically your code works perfectly. I tested it with Excel 2013/VB6 as follows:

```
Sub Lookup()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim c As Integer

c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To c
    For j = 2 To 141

       If Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1) = "Trough" Then
          Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 2) = "T"
       End If


       If Worksheets("Austria").Cells(j, 1) = "Peak" Then
          Worksheets("Austria").Cells(j, 2) = "P"
       End If
   Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

The function to write the values in Excel:

```
Public Function X(tmin2, tmin1, t, tplus1, tplus2)

If t < tmin2 And t < tmin1 And t < tplus1 And t < tplus2 Then
   X = "Trough"
Else
   X = ""
End If


End Function
```

The values in excel were created by custom as well as e.g. `=X(100;100;1;100;100)`.

Comment: I wonder who gave me -1 and for what reason. It took some time to test the code presented here (which was all the OP basically asked for) and it turned out correct, so that's all there is to it. Also I could not just comment with less than 50 reput. Totally retarded behaviour, congrats.

Comment: I gave you a -1, you only posted an answer (just as you stated) because you can't comment. The only thing your answer holds is that the code works and an exact copy from the OP's post. SO is a Q&A site where questions are asked about coding issues/errors and answer that provide the help how to fix it and for future reference for others. Your answer doesn't comply with the SO Q&A, and if the code works then the question should be closed as not a proper question

Comment: I get your point, but I don't have the feeling this was necessary. My answer actually provides useful information to the OP or to anyone in the world with a similar problem who needs a working solution - it confirms its correctness. And see that there was no other way I could have told the OP just that.

Comment: Your answer is a bit of an edge case, but I would personally not downvote or flag it (I just gave you +1). Technically it's not really an *answer answer*, but it's a very helpful addition to the post that I believe belongs here in the answer section since you were not able to add it as a comment. And please don't throw insults around! There comes a point where you need to realize that these are just imaginary internet points, and the real purpose of posting your answer was to help OP out with their problem. No point in getting flustered that someone clicked the wrong arrow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With self generated data it does work, but for some reason excel stores the string/data differently to what the function wants to read when I switch to an index in the VBA function instead of a numerical cell reference. I did make mistake referencing "Austria" rather than placing index "i" in those brackets (this, however, is irrelevant to the error I keep getting). Due to time constraints I reverted to other tactics. If I could get a referral to accurate information on how the types of data in excel work, that would be helpful.